# Azure Website Writing file to a network Drive

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, azure, .net-4.5

I have a service that I currently run on our local IIS machine that will write a file to a specified directory using the following code:

```
//Creating the filepath that is needed
string FilePath = FolderPath.Replace("'", "") 
                + FileName.Replace("'", "").Replace(" ", "")
                  .ToString();

//Writing the file to the correct path
File.WriteAllBytes(FilePath, fileTransferDump.FileBinary);
```

When I change over to an Azure Website how would I make the System write to the file path that I would like to write to.

Basically how do I cause the Azure website to write to a network share.  This is just a normal Azure Website.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Websites don't have the ability to write to off-machine resources using traditional windows file shares.  Your best bet would be to wrap any of this logic in a custom library that redirects these file writes to Azure Blob Storage instead.